# SQLite PDO Databases in PHP

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite, pdo

SO, I've been trying to look for an answer online, but I do not seem to get the answer. I've been reading all of the PHP references on http://php.net, and I still can't find a concrete answer for this.. Anyway.

My question is:

I have a PHP source file, that is loaded in a HTML file via:

```
<form name="input" action="register.php" method="get">
User: <input type="text" name="user"  />
Pass: <input type="text" name="pass"  />
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So far so good, right? So, then I have this .php file:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('sqlite::database:');
    $a = $_GET['user'];
    $b = $_GET['pass'];

    $firstSearchF = $db->prepare('SELECT nome FROM Users WHERE name_U = _nome');
    $firstSearchF->bindParam('_nome', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $firstSearchF->execute();
$firstSearch = $firstSearchF->fetch();

    if(empty($firstSearch))
    {
        $final = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users (name_u,password) VALUES(nome,passW)');
    $final->bindParam('nome', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $final->bindParam('passW', $b, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $final->execute();

    echo 'User Registered Successfully!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Sorry, but the requested user already exists in the database. Try again!';
}
?>
```

Whenever I input something on the form, and hit submit, the output will be the following:

```
"prepare('SELECT nome FROM Users WHERE name_U = _nome'); $firstSearchF->bindParam('_nome', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR); $firstSearchF->execute(); $firstSearch = $firstSearchF->fetch(); if(empty($firstSearch)) { $final = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO Users (name_u,password) VALUES(nome,passW)'); $final->bindParam('nome', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR); $final->bindParam('passW', $b, PDO::PARAM_STR); $final->execute(); echo 'User Registered Successfully!'; } else { echo 'Sorry, but the requested user already exists in the database. Try again!'; } ?>"
```

The only problem is that I understand that the output is what's in after the ->. But why does that happen? I just wanted to test this out, and I can't make the outputs work, as in, what's after the echos.

What can be done to fix this? Any ideas? Thanks before hand. ^^

Answer (score 2):

First thing, enable error reporting for development by placing this at the top of your script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Second, your SQLite DSN is incorrect. It should be either

```
sqlite:/path/to/database/file
```

or

```
sqlite::memory:
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php

Your bind parameter is also incorrect. It should be prefixed with a colon, eg

```
$firstSearchF = $db->prepare('SELECT nome FROM Users WHERE name_U = :nome');
$firstSearchF->bindParam('nome', $a, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Same goes for the other statements and binding.

Lastly, I don't fully believe the code you've posted in your question is the same as it appears in your environment. Could you double check and post any corrections?

Also, submitting credentials via a `GET` form, not cool. Use `POST` instead. Storing plain-text passwords, also a no-no.

---

### Update

Come to think of it, given what you're seeing, I doubt you're running this on a PHP enabled web server. Confirm that you have a running web server with PHP installed as a module or CGI.

Comment: Well, I've read through everything, and I've been changing things too, but I seem to get the same outputs. All I'm doing is creating the .php on notepad++, and then running the html with the form on Firefox. Also, the plaintext passwords are just a matter of testing, because this is for an Uni project, quite simple actually. What I don't get is why I'm having the trouble on the output.

Comment: I think your "update" is right on, is this script even executed as PHP? http://jsfiddle.net/g9Sju/ Too funny... :)

Comment: Well, according to what I've been seeing in class, yes, it is executed as PHP. I don't see any errors in the code, that's why I'm asking this. It makes no sense it doesn't run at all, because a simple echo 'Hello World'; runs perfectly.

Comment: @Nelspike Try a simple test like this `<?php $world = 'sailor'; echo "Hello, $world!"; ?>`

Comment: Well, that that doesn't input anything on the screen.. Kind of weird, now that I think of it. I've had stuff like that running in class perfectly. Even created a script to multiply numbers really quick.

Comment: @Nelspike: You need a server and with PHP installed, you can't just open the file in your browser from any random place on your computer and expect it to execute PHP (HTML will work however because it's run in the browser). See [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html).

Comment: @Nelspike Or my favourite - [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/)